# Django rest framework filtering by dateTime

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, filtering

I'm trying to filter by dateTime in django restFramework.
it seems that it does not work, because it does not filter, it always brings the same results.

Model.py

```
#Modelo Fechas que formara parte del modelo horario
class Fecha(models.Model):
    fecha_inicio = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default='')
    fecha_fin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fecha_inicio, self.fecha_fin

#Modelo Horario
class Horario(models.Model):
    profesional = models.ForeignKey(Profesional, unique=True)
    fechas = models.ManyToManyField(Fecha)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.profesional.user.username
```

View.py

```
class FechaList(generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    serializer_class = FechaSerializer
    queryset = Fecha.objects.all()
    filter_class = HorarioFilter
```

Urls.py

```
 url(r'^horario/$', views.FechaList.as_view())
```

Filters.py

```
   class HorarioFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_start = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="fecha_inicio")

    class Meta:
        model = Fecha
        fields = {
            'date_start': ['lte', 'gte', 'lt', 'gt'],
        }
```

Serializers.py

```
class FechaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fecha
        fields = ('fecha_inicio','fecha_fin')
```

Request: http://127.0.0.1:8000/horario/?date_start__gte=2015-6-28+00:00 . Don't do anything, dont filter but the response it's a listo of "horario" object and give a 200 code.

Thank you!!!! :)

Comment: Could you try to replace in views.py `filter_class=HorarioFilter` to `filter_backends = (HorarioFilter,)`

Comment: With your solution i have this error:  AttributeError at /horario/
'HorarioFilter' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `lt`, `lte`, `gt`, `gte` to the field you want to filter by, like this:
    class HorarioFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Horario
        fields = {
            'fecha__inicio': ['lte', 'gte', 'lt', 'gt'],
        }
```

And your API request would be: `GET {{DOMAIN}}/{{RESOURCES}}/?fecha__inicio__gte=2017-6-28+00:00&fecha__inicio__lt=2017-6-29+00:00:00`

If you want a cleaner or a custom lookup expr for the query param, you can use create an alias like [this](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html?highlight=lookup_expr#declaring-filters):

```
class HorarioFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Horario
        fields = {
            'started__lte': ['fecha__inicio__lte'], 
            'started__gte': ['fecha__inicio__gte'],
        }
```

Then your API request will be like: `GET {{DOMAIN}}/{{RESOURCES}}/?started__gte=2017-6-28+00:00&started__lte=2017-6-29+00:00:00`

And on top of that, assuming you are using the recommended [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/), and you are on the 1.x. If you didn't specify a global filter backends in your DRF setting,  try adding this to your View

```
filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend, )
```

Comment: but, which is the url thati would to send the request? Like tihs?: http://127.0.0.1:8000/horario/?fecha_inicio=2017-11-08T10:00:00

Comment: updated my answer, also added a way for cleaner query params

Comment: I'm updated my question with your changes, but dont work.... dont do anything.... Could you help me, please? Thanks a lot! :)